# Open separate CMD for the Python program from the existing Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code working but it halt the rest process as there is a look for checking in the anther program that I am trying to open from the python:

```
def RunSocket():
    os.system('python "Display Lines.py"')

threading.Thread(target = RunSocket).start()

check_display_active = True

try:
    while check_display_active == True:
        try:
            client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            client.connect((display_host, display_port))
            client.send(str('is_active').encode())
            response = client.recv(4096)
            if response.decode() == "active":
                break
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print("==========================================")
            print("Display not running")
            print(e)
            print("==========================================")
except:
    sys.exit()
```

I wan to run this process in separate CMD so that it can run there without halting my current process.
Please share your advice. I do not know subprocess properly I think it can be solution. But need advise.

Comment: If you are on Windows (which I infer from you mentioning `cmd`), have you tried the `start` shell command? It may help: `os.system('start python "Display Lines.py"')`

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs Thanks I got it.